# imageView get Drawable use getDrawble()

Tags: android

How do ImageView get Drawable using getDrawable()? Why it different from getting image using getBaseContext().getResources().getDrawable()?
Like drawable：R.drawable.l, first set ImageView iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.l); then use iv.getDrawable() and getBaseContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.l).but why it get the different drawable? Use “== “or equals , it is not right. Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0):

iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.l) will also use getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.l),

you invoke getDrawable(R.drawable.l) twice time, will get two different object becase of twice

new ImageDrawable().

you could use Drawable.getConstantState() to compare them. But it will also sometimes fail.